# Hashing an int in Python 3

Tags: python, hash, hex

I would like to show my students that MD5 collides the two integer "messages" given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Collision_vulnerabilities). This is my original demonstration for Python 2.7:

```
from hashlib import md5

m1 = "d131dd02c5e6eec4693d9a0698aff95c2fcab58712467eab4004583eb8fb7f8955ad340609f4b30283e488832571415a085125e8f7cdc99fd91dbdf280373c5bd8823e3156348f5bae6dacd436c919c6dd53e2b487da03fd02396306d248cda0e99f33420f577ee8ce54b67080a80d1ec69821bcb6a8839396f9652b6ff72a70"
m2 = "d131dd02c5e6eec4693d9a0698aff95c2fcab50712467eab4004583eb8fb7f8955ad340609f4b30283e4888325f1415a085125e8f7cdc99fd91dbd7280373c5bd8823e3156348f5bae6dacd436c919c6dd53e23487da03fd02396306d248cda0e99f33420f577ee8ce54b67080280d1ec69821bcb6a8839396f965ab6ff72a70"
# differences                               ^                                                   ^                           ^                                               ^                                                   ^                           ^

print md5(m1.decode("hex")).hexdigest()
print md5(m2.decode("hex")).hexdigest()
```

As expected, it prints twice `79054025255fb1a26e4bc422aef54eb4`.
Now when I try to translate the last two lines into Python 3.5 as:

```
print(md5(int(m1, 16)).hexdigest())
print(md5(int(m2, 16)).hexdigest())
```

All I get is a `TypeError: object supporting the buffer API required` message. The method `decode` no longer works in Python 3, but I am not sure it's a good idea to replace it by `int(m, base)` as above. May be the problem is there, and not with the hash function API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python 2, decoding strings as hex gives you a bytestring still, not integers. Don't try to interpret your hex strings as integers.

Use the [`binascii.unhexlify()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify) to turn your hex strings into a bytestring:

```
from binascii import unhexlify

print(md5(unhexlify(m1)).hexdigest())
```

Note that the same code will work fine in Python 2 as well.

If you want to use decoding anyway, use the [`codecs.decode()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.decode):

```
import codecs

print(md5(codecs.decode(m1, 'hex')).hexdigest())
```

Again, the same code works in Python 2 as well.

Comment: This works like a charm, thanks! I didn't know this module.